# kvm switch with semi\full ddm

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a kvm switch that will support my Logitech unifying receiver.

From my understanding, the only ones capable of that are kvm switches using semi or full DDM. The issue is that most of the kvm's I found are about 150$ or more.
What is the cheapest KVM switch out there (with dvi or hdmi connections) I can get?

I found kvm switches for 20$-35$ on aliexpress - but those use USB emulations which is no good. Am I deceiving myself in believing I can find a kvm in that price range?

Btw, the screen resolution isn't too much of a concern.

--- edit ---

If there are other options that are not DDM that will support Logitech Unifying receiver- I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Welcome on the HwRecs SE! I had voted your post up, if I had not needed to fix it.

Comment: Ts this your Logitech Unifying Receiver? https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/unifying-receiver-usb  Please confirm.

Comment: I believe it is (I didn't buy it separately- It came with my keyboard)

Comment: If you have a source for the suggestion that non-Logitech devices will accept signals from Unifying Receivers, please share that with us by clicking [edit] and adding the link to that web page into your question. I'll see the change to the question, and can use that info to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

A search of [37 screens of listings in the Logitech Knowledgebase](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/search#q=Unifying&s=kbs) found no reference to a comprehensive list offered by Logitech nor any device other than a keyboard, mouse, or other pointing device which are compatible with the [Logitech Unifying Receiver](http://logitech.com/en-us/product/unifying-receiver-usb).

Devices which are compatible have this logo on them, [as per Logitech](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023400913):

[image: Logitech Unifying logo]

Louie H. at Logitech Community Support on 2020-04-23 said only Logitech devices can use the Unifying protocol. The Logitech Unifying Receiver is designed by Logitech only for Logitech Human Input Devices (HID), and uses a proprietary protocol. He did provide a list of devices:

Couch Mouse M515
Logitech Cube
Marathon Mouse M705
Mouse M525-C
Performance Mouse MX
Touch Mouse models M600, and T620
Logitech Wireless Wave Combo models  MK270, MK320, MK360,  MK520, and MK550
Illuminated Living-Room Keyboard K830
Notebook Kit MK605
Wireless All-in-One Keyboard TK820
Wireless Desktops MK320, and MK710
Wireless Illuminated Keyboard K800
Wireless Keyboards K230, K250, K270, K340, K350, and K360
Wireless Mouse models M217, M317, M325, M505, M510, M525, and M560
Wireless Number Pad N305
Wireless Performance Combo MX800
Wireless Rechargeable Touchpad T650
Wireless Solar Keyboard & Marathon Mouse Combo MK750
Wireless Solar Keyboard K750
Wireless Touch Keyboard K400
Wireless Touchpad
Wireless Trackball M570
Wireless Wave Plus Combo MK560
Zone Touch Mouse T400

but no KVM .   A [Quora article](https://www.quora.com/What-devices-can-I-pair-with-my-Logitech-unifying-receiver-other-than-a-mouse-and-keyboard#) also listed the devices provided by Logitech, but no KVM or other non-Logitech device was listed.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Logitech keyboard / mouse and have used several cheap (i.e. non-DDM) KVM switches that worked just fine.

[A four-port model](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08CZC68PH?ref=nb_sb_ss_w_as-ypp-rep_ypp_rep_k0_1_3&crid=3B3SA5ZMY3MTV&sprefix=kvm)
[A two-port model](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08971T526/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I switched from the 2 port model to the 4 port model due to adding a third computer to the mix. Note that there are other issues with this one: one of the computers does not always detect the keyboard / mouse when I switch back to it, resulting in the need to reboot that computer. The other two work just fine with it.

And the display re-calculates (windows get resized etc.). I believe a semi or full DDM model may resolve that.

I got around the USB issue by just using the KVM switch for 2 of the 3 computers (mouse / keyboard) and for all 3 for the display. I have a separate kb/mouse permanently attached to the troublesome computer.